# aggregation with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

The exercise consists in aggregating a numeric vector of values by a combination of factors with data.table in R. Take the following data table as example:

```
require (data.table)
require (plyr)
dtb <- data.table (cbind (expand.grid (month = rep (month.abb[1:3], each = 3),
                                       fac = letters[1:3]),
                          value = rnorm (27)))
```

Notice that every unique combination of 'month' and 'fac' shows up three times. So, when I try to average values by both these factors, I should expect a data frame with 9 unique rows:

```
(agg1 <- ddply (dtb, c ("month", "fac"), function (dfr) mean (dfr$value)))
  month fac          V1
1   Jan   a -0.36030953
2   Jan   b -0.58444588
3   Jan   c -0.15472876
4   Feb   a -0.05674483
5   Feb   b  0.26415972
6   Feb   c -1.62346772
7   Mar   a  0.24560510
8   Mar   b  0.82548140
9   Mar   c  0.18721114
```

However, when aggregating with data.table, I keep getting the results provided by every redundant combination of the two factors:

```
(agg2 <- dtb[, value := mean (value), by = list (month, fac)])
    month fac       value
 1:   Jan   a -0.36030953
 2:   Jan   a -0.36030953
 3:   Jan   a -0.36030953
 4:   Feb   a -0.05674483
 5:   Feb   a -0.05674483
 6:   Feb   a -0.05674483
 7:   Mar   a  0.24560510
 8:   Mar   a  0.24560510
 9:   Mar   a  0.24560510
10:   Jan   b -0.58444588
11:   Jan   b -0.58444588
12:   Jan   b -0.58444588
13:   Feb   b  0.26415972
14:   Feb   b  0.26415972
15:   Feb   b  0.26415972
16:   Mar   b  0.82548140
17:   Mar   b  0.82548140
18:   Mar   b  0.82548140
19:   Jan   c -0.15472876
20:   Jan   c -0.15472876
21:   Jan   c -0.15472876
22:   Feb   c -1.62346772
23:   Feb   c -1.62346772
24:   Feb   c -1.62346772
25:   Mar   c  0.18721114
26:   Mar   c  0.18721114
27:   Mar   c  0.18721114
    month fac       value
```

Is there an elegant way to collapse these results to one row per unique combination of factors with data table?

Comment: Just a small tip: just like when creating a `data.frame`, it is not necessary to use `cbind` when creating the `data.table`

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. Spot on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue (and reasoning) is related to the fact that aggregated value is being *assigned* not just calculated.

It is easier to observe this in action if you look at a data.table with more columns than just the ones being used for the computation.

```
# Therefore, let's add a new column
dtb[, newCol := LETTERS[seq(length(value))]
```

Note that if we just want to *output* the computed value, then expression on the `RHS` as you have it is just fine.

```
# This gives the expected results
dtb[, mean (value), by = list (month, fac)]

# This on the other hand assigns the respective values to *each* row
dtb[, value := mean (value), by = list (month, fac)]
```

In other words, the data is being subsetted to only return unique values.
However, if you want to save this value back into the *SAME* data table (which is what happens when using `:=` operator)
then all rows that are identified in `i` (all rows by defualt) will be assigned a value. (which, when you look at the output with additional columns, makes sense)

Then copying this data.table to agg still sends through all the rows.

Therefore, if you want to copy to a new table, **only those rows from your original table that are unique**, you can

```
a.  wrap the original table inside `unique()` before assigning it
b.  assign the table, above, that is returned when you 
    are not assigning the RHS output (which is what @Arun suggested)
```

An example of `a.` would be:

```
 agg2 <- unique(dtb[, value := mean (value), by = list (month, fac)])
```

---

### The following example might help illustrate.

*(You would need to copy + paste this, as the output is ommitted)*

```
  # SAMPLE DATA, as above
  library(data.table)
  dtb.bak <- data.table (expand.grid (month = rep (month.abb[1:3], each = 3), fac = letters[1:3]), value = rnorm (27))

  #  METHOD 1  # 
  #------------#
  dtb <- copy(dtb.bak)  # restore, from sample data.


  dtb[, value := mean (value), by = list (month, fac)]
  dtb

  # this is what you would like to assign
  unique(dtb)


  #  METHOD 2  # 
  #------------#
  dtb <- copy(dtb.bak)  # restore, from sample data.

  # this is what you would like to assign
  # next two lines are the same, only differnce is column name
  dtb[, mean (value), by = list (month, fac)]
  dtb[, list("mean" = mean (value)), by = list (month, fac)]  # quote marks added for clarity

  # dtb is unchanged. 
  dtb



  # NOW COMPARE THE SAME TWO METHODS, BUT IF THERE IS AN ADDITIOANL COLUMN
  dtb.bak[, newCol := rep(c("A", "B", "A"), length(value)/3)]


  dtb1 <- copy(dtb.bak)  # restore, from sample data.
  dtb2 <- copy(dtb.bak)  # restore, from sample data.


  # Method 1
  dtb1[, value := mean (value), by = list (month, fac)]
  dtb1
  unique(dtb1)

  #  METHOD 2  # 
  dtb2[, list("mean" = mean (value)), by = list (month, fac)]  # quote marks added for clarity
  dtb2

  # METHOD 2, WITH ADDED COLUMNS IN list() in `j`
  dtb2[, list("mean" = mean (value), newCol), by = list (month, fac)]  # quote marks added for clarity
  # notice this has more columns thatn 
  unique(dtb1)
```

Comment: (+1) nice explanation. could you elaborate `a. wrap the table ...`?

Answer (score 6):

You should do:

```
agg2 <- dtb[, list(value = mean(value)), by = list (month, fac)]
```

`:=` will recycle values for `RHS` to fit the number of elements in `LHS`. Do `?':='` to read more about this.

Comment: Note that, as opposed to the OP's original method, if there are additional columns besides the three explicitly named, they will not be passed through to `agg2`

Comment: Yes, but this is more like a `summarise` in `ddply` right? You're reducing the size of your output... I wouldn't expect other variables to be there as I wouldn't know which ones to retain.. right?

Comment: Absolutely, and as far as the OP's requirements this is spot on. Just thought it was worth noting for future googlers